# How can I load a hotel search from the HotelsCombined script?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a hotel search on my website. The hotel search is created by HotelsCombined and they have given me this code to show the hotel search:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://hoteles.gangatravel.es/SearchBox/297018'></script>
```

But I've put the code in my html and does not work, anyone know how I can load the script? I tried it with an iframe and does not work either.

Comment: try remove spaces from url

Comment: I did, I copied wrong the url sorry. But dosnt work too

Answer (score 0):

Well, what exactly do you want it to do?

I can show you the general idea.  That is: the script puts a variable HCSB in the memory.  That variable has properties (= variables of an object) and methods (= functions of an object)

```
<script src="http://hoteles.gangatravel.es/SearchBox/297018"></script>
<script>
// by loading this script, you get a variable HCSB

// so, an example of a variable dump of HCSB
function var_dump() {
  for (i in HCSB) {
    log(i +': '+ HCSB[i]);
  }
}
function log(text) {
  document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += text + '<hr>';
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="var dump" onclick="var_dump()">
<div id="log"></div>
```

EDIT: I presume you want something like this: http://hoteles.gangatravel.es/

You want such a form on your site.  But would you mind elaborating a little more?

Oh yes, forget iframe.  This is an javascript API.

Comment: Yes i want this search box like hoteles.gangatravel.es

Comment: I created the hotels search with Hotelscombined and they gave me this script to put it in my html<script src="http://hoteles.gangatravel.es/SearchBox/297018"></script>